# Можно ли изменить цвет WebView?

Tags: java, android, webbrowser

Можно ли изменить цвет webview до того, как загрузилась страница? На секунду появляется белый экран, а только потом загружается сайт

Comment: `webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));` ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:

```
WebView synopsis;
synopsis=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.synopsis);
synopsis.getSettings();
synopsis.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Надеюсь вам помог мой ответ!

Answer (score 1):

> На секунду появляется белый экран, а только потом загружается сайт

Можно даже лучше сделать! Как я сделал у себя в приложении.

**Шаг #1**

До загрузки `WebView` (если у Вас оно во `Fragment`'е, то в методе `onCreate()` / `onAttach()` можно) вызываете `PregressDialog`, заранее объявив переменную типа `ProgressDialog` глобальной.

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext, R.style.AppThemeDialogStyle);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false); // нельзя отменить диалог нажатием за его пределами
progressDialog.setTitle("Загрузка");
progressDialog.setMessage("Пожалуйста, дождитесь завершения ...");
progressDialog.show();
```

**Шаг #2**

В `onCreate()` (если Activity) или `onCreateView()` (для `Fragment`'а)
 инициализируете `WebView`, грузите информацию из сети. Когда данные готовы, вызываете

```
if (progressDialog != null) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
// показать здесь WebView
```

Comment: целый диалог ради загрузки?

Comment: @Flippy, да. Что Вас смущает ?

Comment: не, ничего. просто помню в одном приложении окно жестко бесило при каждой загрузке

Comment: @Flippy зато Вы знаете, что приложение "живое" еще и скоро Вы получите результат своего запроса. То есть приложение отреагировало на действие. :-)

Comment: я про то что окно слишком большой датчик реакции на действие. оно закрывает собой все. `SwipeRefreshLayout` лучший выбор.

Comment: @Flippy Swipe - для обновления данных, а не для загрузки))) Деликатный вопрос получается))

Comment: аааа!! простите  не так понял)